# Can I open Ionic 3 Barcode Scanner in an area? Like in a div

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

Can I open Ionic 3 Barcode Scanner in an area? Like, in a div. When I click, the scanner open over the application.

Comment: if it loads properly without any issue, then you can. its just CSS thing

Comment: But, when I click on the  scanner, it opens over the application. Cant access the css then.

Comment: I misunderstood your question, apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because as per the documents,

> The Barcode Scanner Plugin opens a **camera view** and automatically scans
> a barcode, returning the data back to you.

That means, the camera view is rendered over the cordova webview.

[QR scanner plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner) however, renders camera view behind Cordova webview allowing you to show the scanner in a particular area.